# Почему событие onscroll срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу, чтобы блок `NavigationPanel` перемещался при прокрутке страницы.
Так, как сделал я, не работает. Складывается впечатление, что событие `onscroll` выполняется всего один раз.

Кто знает, объясните почему, будьте добры, и подскажите как добиться нужного эффекта.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("NavigationPanel");
window.onscroll = function() {
  obj.style.top = '45px';
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFE0;
  white-space: normal;
}
#header_title {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 570px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 30px;
}
#headImg {
  background-image: url(images/head.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background-size: cover;
}
#TopMenu {
  vertical-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 2em;
}
#TopMenu ul li {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  min-height: 15%;
}
#TopBorder {
  position: relative;
  background: #006400;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 12px;
}
#Main {
  background: #002000;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
#ContentBox {
  background: black;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  float: right;
  min-width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: auto;
}
#NavigationPanel {
  position: absolute;
  border-color: green;
  background: black;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  float: left;
  width: 11%;
  min-width: 11%;
  list-style-image: url(images/ring3.png);
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.rozdel {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#first {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.menu {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.image {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.image_fl {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}
.image_fr {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}
.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.text p {
  text-indent: 25px;
}
li {
  margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFE0;
}
a:visited {
  color: #FFFFE0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  /*font-size:18px;*/
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Lord OF The Rings
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header_title">Добро пожаловать на портал
    <br/>об удивительном мире Средиземья</div>
  <div id="headImg"></div>
  <div id="TopBorder"></div>
  <div id="TopMenu" class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page.html">Главная</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Кинотрилогия</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Об авторе</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="page.html"> Бестиарий</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Краткая история мира</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="Main">

    <div id="ContentBox">
      <div id="tema1">

        <div class="text">
          <div class="rozdel" id="first">Властелин колец (кинотрилогия)</div>
          <div class="image image_fr">
            <img src="images/trilogy.jpg" />

          </div>
          <p>Кинотрилогия «Властели́н коле́ц» (англ. The Lord of the Rings; 2001—2003) — культовая, поставленная режиссёром Питером Джексоном серия из трёх связанных единым сюжетом кинофильмов, представляющая собой экранизацию романа Дж. Р. Р. Толкина «Властелин
            колец».
            <br>В трилогию входят фильмы:
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>2001 — Властелин колец: Братство Кольца (англ. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring)</li>
            <li>2002 — Властелин колец: Две крепости (англ. The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers)</li>
            <li>2003 — Властелин колец: Возвращение короля (англ. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King)</li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            «Властелин колец» является одним из самых крупных проектов в истории кино. Его реализация заняла восемь лет; все три фильма были сняты одновременно в Новой Зеландии, родной стране Джексона. У каждого из фильмов трилогии есть специальная расширенная версия,
            выпущенная на DVD спустя год после выхода соответствующей театральной версии. Фильмы следуют за основной сюжетной линией книги, но опускают некоторые существенные элементы повествования, включают дополнения и отклонения от исходного материала.
          </p>
          <p>
            Сюжет трилогии следует за хоббитом Фродо Бэггинсом, который идёт в поход вместе с Братством Кольца с целью уничтожения Кольца Всевластия. Это необходимо для окончательной победы над его создателем, Тёмным Властелином Сауроном. Братство распадается, и
            Фродо продолжает путешествие вместе с верным спутником Сэмом и предательским проводником Голлумом. Тем временем Арагорн, наследник трона Гондора, и волшебник Гэндальф объединяют Свободные народы Средиземья для противостояния армиям Саурона
            в Войне Кольца.
          </p>
          <p>
            Трилогия имела большой финансовый успех и является одной из самых прибыльных серий фильмов. Фильмы были положительно приняты критиками и выиграли 17 премий «Оскар» из 30 номинаций. Заключительный фильм трилогии, «Возвращение короля», получил все 11 «Оскаров»,
            на которые был номинирован, что является рекордным количеством наград Американской киноакадемии для одного фильма (за всю историю столько же статуэток смогли получить только два фильма: «Бен-Гур» Уильяма Уайлера и «Титаник» Джеймса Кэмерона).
            Трилогия также известна использованием инновационных визуальных эффектов, в частности, Голлум стал первым персонажем, полностью созданным с помощью технологии захвата движения.
          </p>
          <div class="rozdel" id="plot">Сюжет трилогии</div>

          <h3>
Братство Кольца
</h3>

          <p>
            Всё началось с отливки великих Колец. Три из них были отданы бессмертным эльфам, семь — пещерным гномам, а девять — королям людского рода. Но в пылающей пещере вулкана Ородруин Тёмный властелин Саурон тайно выковал ещё одно — Единое Кольцо, призванное
            подчинить себе все остальные. В этом Кольце была сосредоточена вся злоба и мощь повелителя Мордора, задумавшего положить конец свободе народов Средиземья и подчинить их себе навеки. Последний союз людей и эльфов выступил против армий Мордора.
            Исилдуру, сыну павшего в бою короля, удалось отрубить Саурону палец и завладеть Кольцом. Но оно поработило его волю и привело к гибели. Кольцо было потеряно и пролежало на дне реки две с половиной тысячи лет. Затем оно попало в руки существа
            по имени Голлум, который обладал им в течение столетий, пока Кольцо не было найдено хоббитом Бильбо Бэггинсом.
          </p>
          <div class="image image_fl">
            <img src="images/bOfTheRing.jpg" />
          </div>
          <p>
            60 лет спустя Бильбо оставляет Кольцо своему племяннику Фродо. Узнав, что это то Кольцо, которое в своё время принадлежало Тёмному властелину, волшебник Гэндальф Серый предупреждает Фродо, что прислужники Саурона будут искать его. Фродо со своим слугой
            Сэмом покидают Шир. Гэндальф является за советом к главе своего ордена, Саруману Белому, который сообщает, что из крепости Минас Моргул на охоту за Кольцом выехали Чёрные Всадники. Сам же Саруман перешёл на сторону Мордора. Гэндальф отказывается
            присоединиться к нему и попадает в плен.
          </p>
          <p>
            По дороге в Бри Фродо и Сэм случайно встречают хоббитов Пиппина и Мерри. Они едва не попадаются Чёрным Всадникам, но успевают в последний момент бежать из Шира. В трактире «Гарцующий пони» Фродо встречает следопыта Арагорна, который вызывается привести
            их к Ривенделлу. Во время путешествия назгулы нападают на хоббитов. Арагорн прогоняет их, но Фродо тяжело ранен моргульским клинком. Приехавшая эльфийка Арвен на быстром коне доставляет Фродо в Ривенделл и топит преследующих её назгулов в
            разбушевавшейся реке. Её отец, Владыка Элронд, исцеляет Фродо. Тем временем Гэндальф бежал из плена и прибыл в Ривенделл. На совете Элронд требует уничтожить Кольцо, бросив его в пламя Роковой горы, которая находится в Мордоре. Фродо вызывается
            сделать это. Его готовы сопровождать Сэм, Пиппин, Мерри, Гэндальф и Арагорн, к которым присоединяются эльф Леголас, гном Гимли и Боромир, человек из Гондора. Элронд называет этот отряд Братством Кольца.
          </p>
          <p>
            Во время перехода через подземные копи Мории на Братство нападают орки и балрог, демон древних времён. Гэндальф обрушивает мост с балрогом в пропасть, но тот, обвив мага своим бичом, увлекает его за собой в бездну. Выйдя из пещер, отряд приходит в лес
            Лориэн, где их принимают правители, Келеборн и Галадриэль. Эльфы снабжают путников всем необходимым и отправляют их в лодках по реке Андуин. Саруман высылает на их поиски отряд орков новосотворённого племени — урук-хай. На стоянке Боромир
            требует от Фродо отдать ему Кольцо, чтобы спасти его народ. Фродо отказывается, Боромир пытается отнять Кольцо, но хоббит, став невидимым, ускользает от него. В это время отряд атакуют орки. Гимли и Леголас успевают на помощь Арагорну и слышат
            рог Боромира. Тот защищал хоббитов, но был смертельно ранен стрелами. Орки захватывают в плен Пиппина и Мерри. Арагорн, Гимли и Леголас решают преследовать орков и выручить друзей. Фродо и Сэм переплывают Андуин и направляются в Мордор.
          </p>
          <h3>
Две крепости
</h3>
          <p>
            Братство распалось, и теперь каждому предстоит свой собственный путь. Хранитель Кольца Фродо Бэггинс в сопровождении верного Сэма Гэмджи отправляется вглубь зловещего Мордора. Ведь только там, в стране недремлющего Огненного Ока Саурона, можно уничтожить
            злосчастное «сокровище». Друзей преследует Голлум — существо, околдованное Кольцом много лет назад. Единственная цель бедолаги — завладеть своей «прелестью», и ради этого Голлум готов пойти даже на убийство хоббитов. Сэму и Фродо удаётся схватить
            злодея и заставить его поклясться на Кольце, что он не причинит им вреда и, более того, станет проводником в Чёрную страну…
          </p>
          <p>
            Арагорн, Леголас и Гимли устремляются на поиски Мерри и Пиппина, захваченных орками Сарумана. Бывший белый маг, вступивший в союз с Тёмным властелином Мордора, создал собственных бойцов — огромных урук-хай. Путь бегущих в сторону Изенгарда орков пролегает
            через земли Рохана. Без отдыха и сна человек, эльф и гном преследуют урук-хай в надежде, что хоббиты ещё живы. Никто не предполагает, что поиски приведут их в волшебный лес Фангорн, где они встретят того, чью гибель оплакивали…
          </p>
          <div class="image image_fr">
            <img src="images/TwoTowers.jpg" />
          </div>
          <p>
            Рохан готовится к войне. 10-тысячная армия урук-хаев, созданная Саруманом, устремляется к Хельмовой Пади — там, в ущелье, защищённом со всех сторон горными отрогами, прячется неприступная крепость Хорнбург. Женщины, старики и дети скрываются в глубоких
            пещерах, а на защиту цитадели выходят мужчины — мальчики, которым едва достанет сил натянуть лук, крестьяне, ни разу в жизни не державшие меч, и горстка воинов-рохиррим. В мрачном безмолвии ночи они ждут приближения врага, надвигающегося бесконечной
            чёрной рекой. Люди готовы дать последний бой, и никто не надеется дожить до рассвета…
          </p>
          <p>
            Близится час последней битвы за Средиземье. Десятитысячная армия Сарумана разгромлена в Хельмовой Пади, а сам колдун выведен из игры и заперт в Ортханке. Поражение разъярило повелителя зла Саурона, и в глубине Мордора тёмные силы собираются в кулак и
            готовятся к нападению на Белый город — прекрасный Минас-Тирит, древнюю столицу Гондора и цитадель рода Людей.
          </p>


          <p>
            Гэндальф и Арагорн предупреждают короля Рохана Теодена о готовящемся нападении. Маг отправляется в Гондор, прихватив с собой Пиппина. Небо над Минас-Тиритом заволакивают чёрные тучи, ползущие из Мордора. Наместник Дэнетор, отец Боромира, оплакивает своего
            любимца и не собирается готовиться к войне, хотя его младший сын Фарамир, охраняющий подступы к столице, неоднократно предупреждал об угрозе. И когда вторжение орков начинается, оборону Белого города возглавляет Гэндальф. В Рохане получают
            сообщение о начале войны, и Теоден отдаёт приказ о выступлении рохиррим.
          </p>
          <p>
            Несметные полчища орков, троллей и прочих жутких порождений Мордора заполняют Пелленорское поле и подступают к Минас-Тириту. Осадные орудия громят величественные башни, всё меньше надежды остаётся в сердцах людей, оглушённых нечеловеческими воплями назгулов.
          </p>
          <p>
            Арагорн, последний из наследников трона Гондора, преодолевает страхи и сомнения и отправляется в сопровождении гнома Гимли и эльфа Леголаса на Тропу Мёртвых. Если ему удастся уговорить армию призраков выполнить его волю, то у людей ещё есть шанс уцелеть
            в смертельном поединке.
          </p>
          <p>
            Но настоящая битва со злом состоится не на полях сражений. Две одинокие фигурки, обессилевшие в долгом походе, голодные, забывшие о тепле и свете, бредут за своим сомнительным провожатым. Голлум ведёт хоббитов в страшную ловушку. Сэм подозревает его в
            измене, но Фродо, душа которого по мере приближения к логову Саурона всё больше попадает под власть Кольца, уверен в честности Голлума. Преодолев лестницу с бесчисленным количеством ступенек над захваченной назгулами крепостью Минас Моргул,
            Хранитель оказывается в пещере, где властвует громадная паучиха Шелоб…
          </p>
          <p>
            Мужество, преданность, любовь и самоотверженная дружба — на одной чаше весов. На другой же — предательство, страх, безудержная злоба и жажда власти…
          </p>
          <h3>
Возвращение короля
</h3>
          <p>
            Хоббиты Фродо и Сэм, используя Голлума в качестве проводника, продолжают путь к Ородруину. Фродо верит поклявшемуся в верности Голлуму. Но Сэм понимает, что Голлум попытается уничтожить их при первой возможности — он под властью Кольца. Голлум строит
            козни и всячески пытается поссорить хоббитов. Тем временем, после победы в Хельмовой Пади, войско Теодена возвращается в Эдорас. В первую же ночевку Перегрин Тук крадет у Гэндальфа палантир, в котором видит Око Саурона. Чтобы спасти хоббита
            от Ока, Гэндальф увозит его в Минас-Тирит.
          </p>
          <p>
            Войска Мордора под предводительством Короля-чародея, самого верного слуги Саурона, захватили Осгилиат, город, стоящий на реке Андуин, то есть, фактически, напали на Гондор. Саурон подозревал, что Кольцо находится в Гондоре. Он полагал, что Кольцо хотят
            использовать против него, а не уничтожить.
          </p>
          <div class="image image_fl">
            <img src="images/rOfTheKing.jpg" />
          </div>
          <p>
            Следуя своему коварному плану, Голлум приводит хоббитов в пещеру гигантской паучихи Шелоб (порождения древней Унголиант). Шелоб ранит Фродо и парализует его ядом, но Сэму удается прогнать паучиху. Думая, что Фродо мертв, Сэм забирает Кольцо и решает продолжить
            путь. Проходивший мимо отряд орков захватывает Фродо, а спрятавшийся в пещере Шелоб Сэм узнаёт, что хозяин жив, и отправляется в крепость Кирит Унгол его выручать. Деля добычу, орки передрались друг с другом из-за мифриловой кольчуги Фродо,
            и хоббитам удалось вырваться на свободу. Сэм возвращает Фродо Кольцо, не успевшее подчинить себе его волю.
          </p>
          <p>
            Тем временем силы Тьмы начали осаду Минас-Тирита. Использовались катапульты, а также таран под названием Гронд. В армии Саурона, кроме орков, были люди, тролли, мумаки, а главное — назгулы во главе с предводителем, Королём-Чародеем Ангмара. Назгулы летали
            на крылатых существах, похожих на драконов. Их присутствие и леденящие душу крики внушали ужас защитникам города.
          </p>

          <p>
            Уже много веков с момента гибели последнего короля Гондором правили наместники. Последний из них, Дэнетор, был мудрым и сильным властителем, но его разум был ослаблен горем от известия о смерти старшего сына Боромира. Вдобавок его младший сын Фарамир,
            вернувшись со своими людьми из-за восточного берега Андуина, рассказывает отцу о встрече с Фродо и Сэмом и их странном проводнике Голлуме, а также об избранном ими опасном пути через перевал Кирит Унгол. То, что Фарамир упустил Кольцо Всевластья,
            приводит Дэнетора в ярость, и он посылает Фарамира отбить у орков Осгилиат, а фактически — на верную смерть, так как силы неравны. Отряд гибнет, Фарамир возвращается серьёзно раненым. Думая, что сын умер, а надежды на спасение Гондора нет,
            Дэнетор пытается устроить погребальный костёр для себя и своего сына, но благодаря Перегрину Туку, а также вмешательству Гэндальфа, Фарамир был спасён, но Дэнетор погиб. Руководство защитой города взял на себя Гэндальф.
          </p>
          <p>
            Гэндальф, являясь одним из майар, был послан с Заокраинного Запада для помощи свободным народам Средиземья, но он мог лишь наставлять их в нелёгкой борьбе. Вступать в бой он мог только с равным себе соперником — им стал Король-Чародей. Поначалу битва
            шла со значительным перевесом сил Саурона, которым удалось взломать оборону Минас Тирита и ворваться на его верхние уровни. Однако на рассвете подошли всадники Рохана, давние союзники Гондора. С ними были хоббит Мерри и Эовин, и ими был повержен
            Король-Чародей, которому в давние времена было сделано пророчество о том, что он падёт не от руки смертного мужа. Но при этом погиб также и король Рохана, Теоден, которого после той битвы назвали «Прославленным».
          </p>
          <p>
            Силы Мордора не иссякали. В их поддержку должны были прийти чёрные корабли с пиратами Умбара; но прошедшие Путём Мертвых Арагорн, Леголас и Гимли, заручившиеся поддержкой Войска Мёртвых, перехватили корабли и пришли на помощь Минас-Тириту. Битва была
            выиграна силами Запада (а точнее, призраками, которые во исполнение древней клятвы повиновались Арагорну как королю Гондора). Арагорн, как и обещал, освободил Мёртвых от клятвы, и призраки исчезли. После битвы на Пеленнорских полях состоялся
            Совет, на котором было принято невероятное решение — подойти всей оставшейся армией к воротам Мордора и вызвать Саурона на сражение. Без шансов на победу — только отвлечь Око и дать возможность Фродо исполнить миссию. Саурон не подозревал
            об этом плане и был уверен, что Кольцо используют в грядущем сражении.
          </p>
          <p>
            Измученные хоббиты добираются до подножия Ородруина, и, когда у Фродо не хватает сил идти, Сэм на своих плечах поднимает его на гору. У самой расщелины на хоббитов нападает Голлум, но уже не может помешать им. Стоя на краю пропасти, Фродо понимает, что
            не может уничтожить Кольцо, надевает его и объявляет своим. Неожиданная развязка наступает с появлением Голлума, который отнимает Кольцо, откусив Фродо палец. Фродо после недолгой борьбы сталкивает Голлума в жерло Ородруина, сам падает в пропасть,
            но удерживается за скалу. Подоспевший Сэм вытаскивает друга. Таким образом Кольцо было уничтожено. С уничтожением Кольца цитадель Саурона разрушилась, а войско Мордора обратилось в бегство. Началось извержение вулкана Ородруин. На помощь Фродо
            и Сэму приходят Орлы, вынесшие их из пылающей лавы.
          </p>
          <p>
            Арагорн становится королём Гондора и женится на эльфийской принцессе Арвен. Хоббиты возвращаются в Шир. Сэм женится на Рози Коттон. Фродо одолевают приступы болезни, вызванной слишком долгим контактом с Кольцом. Постепенно он понимает, что не сможет вернуться
            к обычной жизни, и решает использовать дарованную им с Бильбо возможность — уйти вместе с эльфами на Запад. Мерри, Пиппин и Сэм провожают их в Гавань; на том же корабле покидают Средиземье Гэндальф, Галадриэль и Элронд.
          </p>
          <div class="rozdel" id="project">Развитие проекта</div>
          <p>
            Первое знакомство Питера Джексона с «Властелином колец» произошло во время просмотра одноимённого мультфильма Ральфа Бакши. Впоследствии он прочёл книгу во время двенадцатичасовой поездки в поезде из Веллингтона в Окленд. Джексон рассматривал возможность
            экранизации романа с 1995 года. С учётом развития CGI после выхода «Парка юрского периода» Джексон приступил к планированию фэнтезийного фильма, который был бы относительно серьёзным и реалистичным. К октябрю он и его жена Фрэн Уолш объединились
            с владельцем Miramax Films Харви Вайнштейном для переговоров с Саулом Зейнцем, который обладал правами на книгу с начала 1970-х, с целью экранизации «Хоббита» и двух фильмов, основанных на «Властелине колец». Переговоры остановились, так как
            Universal Studios предложила Джексону снять ремейк «Кинг-Конга». В дальнейшем оказалось, что Зейнц не имел прав на экранизацию «Хоббита». К апрелю 1996 года всё ещё не был решён вопрос о правах.
          </p>
          <p>
            Когда Universal отменила проект «Кинг-Конг» в 1997 году, Джексон сразу получил поддержку Вайнштейна и начал шестинедельный процесс разбирательства в принадлежности прав. Джексон попросил своего друга, режиссёра Косту Боутса написать синопсис книги, сам
            же начал перечитывать роман. Два-три месяца спустя Джексон и Уолш написали свой проект сценария (англ.)русск.[8]. Первый из фильмов должен был закончиться на смерти Сарумана и отправлении Гэндальфа с Пиппином в Минас Тирит. В этом проекте
            Гваихир и Гэндальф посещают Эдорас после побега из Ортханка, Бильбо принимает участие в Совете Элронда, Голлум нападает на Фродо, когда Братство ещё не распалось, Сэм смотрит в Зеркало Галадриэль; присутствуют фермер Мэггот, Глорфиндел, Радагаст,
            Элладан и Элрохир. Они представили свой проект Харви и Бобу Вайнштейну и согласовали создание двух фильмов с бюджетом 75 миллионов долларов.</p>
          <div class="rozdel" id="otherFacts">Другие факты</div>
          <ul>
            <li>Режиссёр фильма, Питер Джексон, появился в фильмах камео: в «Братстве кольца» как человек, жующий морковь, — неподалёку от таверны «Гарцующий Пони»; во второй части он был защитником Хельмовой Пади (в сцене защиты моста он метнул копьё в орка);
              в третьей части (только в расширенной версии) он играет пирата, которого застрелил Леголас. Вместе с Питером Джексоном роли пиратов исполнили и другие руководители съемок фильма: Рик Поррас, Ричард Тейлор, Эндрю Лесни и Джино Асеведо.</li>
            <li>Во всех трёх фильмах играют сын и дочь Питера Джексона. В «Братстве Кольца», в начале фильма, когда Бильбо на своём дне рождения рассказывает хоббитятам историю про троллей, в первом ряду детей сидят мальчик и девочка (хоббитята); в «Двух
              крепостях», когда люди прячутся в Хельмовой Пади, в одном из эпизодов можно заметить всё тех же двух детей (уже жителей Рохана); а в «Возвращении короля», когда Фарамир уезжает на штурм Осгилиата, во время проводов также можно заметить тех
              же самых двоих детей, но уже в роли жителей Минас Тирита.</li>
            <li>Восемь из девяти членов Братства сделали себе татуировку в виде эльфийского символа «9». У Элайджи Вуда татуировка находится внизу живота, у Шона Эстина и Билли Бойда — на лодыжке, у Орландо Блума — на предплечье, у Иэна МакКеллена, Доминика
              Монахэна, Виго Мортенсена и Шона Бина — на плече. Джон Рис-Дэвис отказался делать себе татуировку. Режиссёр Питер Джексон также сделал себе татуировку в виде эльфийского символа «10».</li>
            <li>Исполнитель роли Сарумана — британский актер Кристофер Ли — выразил недовольство тем, что сцена гибели Сарумана, которая должна была присутствовать во второй части кинотрилогии, была вырезана из прокатной версии. Эта сцена была включена только
              в расширенное издание трилогии на DVD.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sod"></div>
    <div id="NavigationPanel" class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#first">Властелин колец</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#plot">Сюжет трилогии</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#project">Развитие проекта</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#otherFacts">Другие факты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById("NavigationPanel");

    window.onscroll = function() {
      obj.style.top += '45px';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вот так? http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/49T4d/3/ или так http://www.magentawave.com/2013/02/simple-jquery-floating-block.html или вот http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20130620/

Comment: используйте `position:fixed` вместо `position:absolute`

Comment: @ArcherGodson, я обновил тот фидл для лучшей демонстрации. Можете использовать эту версию: http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/49T4d/

Comment: Я в конечном итоге хочу, чтобы было как здесь:http://theormech.univer.kharkov.ua . И еще я хочу понять, почему событие onscroll( а я ему присваиваю функцию) выполняется всего один раз. Ведь сколько раз я прокручу колесиком, столько раз оно должно выполнятся, то есть должна вызываться присвоенная мной ф-ия.

Answer (score 1):

**Самый простой вариант:**

```
var obj = document.getElementById("NavigationPanel");

document.onscroll = function() {
    obj.style.position = 'fixed';
    obj.style.top = '45px';
}
```

Хотя тут даже функция не нужна:

**Вариант еще проще:**

```
var obj = document.getElementById("NavigationPanel");

obj.style.position = 'fixed';
obj.style.top = '45px';
```